# 'Not authorized to access this resource' when logged in user clicks download link

Tags: error-message, member, download

A user has received this message 'Not authorized to access this resource' when logged in and attempting to download a file by a link. The file was a .zip. I've tested this, but could not replicate the error. Could it be because the user's session had ended?

Comment: What is a Craft-styled "Not authorized to access this resource" message or a web-server styled one?

Comment: Thanks Brad - I'll need to find out more info

Comment: Turns out this is a web server error, and not Craft, so have closed the post